# Running ASP.NET Core on Worker Service in .NET 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core-3.0

I have managed to build a Worker Service and added ASP.NET Core API to the service which is working fine. The problem that I'm facing is installing it as windows service. Since the upgrade to .NET 3.0 there are so many breaking changes especially with `HostBuilder`

Below is my `Program class`

```
 public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseWindowsService()
            .ConfigureServices((hostcontext, svc) =>
            {
                svc.AddHostedService<Worker>();
            });

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .UseKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
                {
                    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(1044);
                    serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5);
                });
```

When I run it like so it fails to pick the WebHost Builder, and when I run with just the WebHost builder it fails to install the service on the destination server.

Kindly assist I would like to leverage the advantages of both `IWebHostBuilder` and `IHostBuilder` but I don't know how to combine them in the `static main` method.

Below are other files;

`StartUp`

```
 public void ConfigureServices(Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();

            ////Add Controllers
            //services.AddTransient<SalesForceDataLoaderController>();


            //Add DB Dependency Injection
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));

            services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.UseCamelCasing(true);
            }).AddControllersAsServices();
            services.AddDbContext<SalesForceReportLoaderContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(this.APIdb));

            services.AddScoped<IRepositoryWrapper, RepositoryWrapper>();
            services.AddScoped<ILogger, Logger<SalesForceDataLoaderController>>();
            services.AddScoped<ILogger, Logger<ActisureWhatsAppController>>();
            services.AddScoped<ILogger, Logger<PureWhatsAppController>>();

            services.AddSingleton(typeof(IRepository<>), typeof(Repository<>));
            services.AddSingleton<ISalesforceLoaderRepository, SalesforceLoaderRepository>();
            services.AddSingleton<IActWhatsAppClaimStatusRepo, ActWhatsAppClaimStatusRepo>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPureWhatsAppClaimStatusRepo, PureWhatsAppClaimStatusRepo>();
            services.AddSingleton<IPureWhatsAppPolicyDetailsRepo, PureWhatsAppPolicyDetailsRepo>();


        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseMvc();
            //app.UseRouting();

        }
```

and my `worker class`

```
 public class Worker : BackgroundService
    {
        private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;

        public Worker(ILogger<Worker> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        public override Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Service Starting at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            return base.StartAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
        {
            while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
            {
                try
                {
                    //Run a request

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogError(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("Salesforce Service running at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
                await Task.Delay(2500, stoppingToken);
            }
        }

        public override Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Service Stop at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            return base.StopAsync(cancellationToken);
        }

        public override void Dispose()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Resources released at: {time}", DateTimeOffset.Now);
            base.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

### EDIT

I have now installed the service normally using `svc` but I keep getting this error

```
[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.
```

Comment: Error messages would be useful. What's `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()`? If its a profile directory (`C:\Users\xxx\yyy\`) then it cant work, windows services typically run w/o a profile (such as network services group)

Comment: I have tried that and I'm getting this error `[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:

The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.`
When trying to start the service

Comment: I was more meaning the error message from your .NET Core application

Comment: The application is running ok on debug mode, I'm suspecting the error am getting when deploying that is `[SC] StartService FAILED 1053:` is as a result of the missing `UseWindowService` injection in the WebHostBuilder

Comment: Could this be true?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue and deployed the service locally on my machine; it turns out the packages were separated that is; `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WindowsServices`and `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.WindowsServices`

So all I had to do is add the package and refactor the `program.cs` as shown below;

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsService();

        }

public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseContentRoot(Path.GetDirectoryName(Process.GetCurrentProcess().MainModule.FileName))
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseKestrel((context, serverOptions) =>
                {
                    serverOptions.ListenAnyIP(1044);
                    serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.5);
                });
```

For more context see this [link](https://elanderson.net/2018/09/host-asp-net-core-application-as-a-windows-service/)

Comment: You can also solve the problem adding self-contained method to the publish profile, thanks for the solution you provide.